# Classloading issue of LoginModules in a wildfly security domain

Tags: security, wildfly-10

I have a strange behavior with the following security domain:

```
                <security-domain name="Login-JBoss">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisServerLoginModule" flag="requisite" module="com.agfa.orbis.security">
                        <module-option name="datasource" value="java:/OracleDS"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.BearerTokenLoginModule" flag="sufficient" module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core">
                        <module-option name="keycloak-config-file" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/keycloak.json"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisLdapLoginModule" flag="sufficient" module="com.agfa.orbis.security">
                        <module-option name="try_first_pass" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="datasource" value="java:/OracleDS"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisDatabaseLoginModule" flag="required" module="com.agfa.orbis.security">
                        <module-option name="try_first_pass" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="datasource" value="java:/OracleDS"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

As you see there are three LoginModules defined in the module `com.agfa.orbis.security` and one is defined in the module `org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core`. When I try to authenticate against the security domain I got the following output in my server log (I deleted some not relevant rows in the middle marked with the dots):

```
    2017-01-12 08:31:17,495 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-12) () PBOX00224: End getAppConfigurationEntry(Login-JBoss), AuthInfo: AppConfigurationEntry[]:
[0]
LoginModule Class: com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisServerLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: requisite
Options:
name=datasource, value=java:/OracleDS
[1]
LoginModule Class: org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.BearerTokenLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: sufficient
Options:
name=keycloak-config-file, value=D:\views\oas\oas-08042800\server\orbis-as-08.04.28.00.a20170104195120-DACHL\standalone\configuration/keycloak.json
[2]
LoginModule Class: com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisLdapLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: sufficient
Options:
name=try_first_pass, value=true
name=datasource, value=java:/OracleDS
[3]
LoginModule Class: com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisDatabaseLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required
Options:
name=try_first_pass, value=true
name=datasource, value=java:/OracleDS

..........

2017-01-12 08:31:17,499 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-12) () PBOX00236: Begin initialize method
2017-01-12 08:31:17,524 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-12) () PBOX00206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: LoginModule-Klasse kann nicht gefunden werden: org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.BearerTokenLoginModule from [Module "deployment.orbis-framework.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:794)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:406)
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345)
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:323)
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verifyCredential(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:123)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.JAASIdentityManagerImpl.verify(JAASIdentityManagerImpl.java:94)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.BasicAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(BasicAuthenticationMechanism.java:167)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:245)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:263)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:231)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:125)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:99)
    at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:92)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-01-12 08:31:17,524 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-12) () PBOX00201: End isValid, result = false
```

I 'm surprised to find the "ClassNotFoundException" only in debug mode but it is not my main question at all. The issue I'm surprising is that It works fine when I define the module `org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core` as a global module (that also indicates that the modules are installed correctly). 
During testing I also detect that I get the same error but for the class `com.agfa.orbis.security.auth.OrbisServerLoginModule` when I delete the last two LoginModules from my configuration. So it seems to be: only the classes of the last defined module are part of the classpath, but this is just an assumption.

Do you have any idea what's going wrong here? Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while trying to secure some web service with Keycloak.

The solution I found was to add the dependency on the Keycloak module (namely the "keycloak-adapter-core" module) in the generated MANIFEST.MF.

If you are using Maven to build your project, you can achieve this by configuring the "maven-jar-plugin" ("archive" is the relevant part).

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Dependencies>org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core</Dependencies>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Your generated MANIFEST.MF should have this entry:

```
Dependencies: org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core
```

Maybe the same error is happening with your Orbis config. You may add both dependencies separated by a comma.

For reference:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Manifest+module+information

Comment: Your proposal is working when all deployments are in your responsibility and you can add easily the manifest dependency. We have a lot of deployments from different teams that are using the described security domain, so every team have to add the dependency to every WAR or EAR. We found an other solution to fix the error (see below).

Answer (score 1):

We solved the error by adding a dependency of the 'org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-core' to the module.xml of 'com.agfa.orbis.security'. This module is managed by us, so it was easy to implement. I cannot explain why it works but it works :-/